# Highest number of collabrations between an actor and a director

Tags: cinema-history

I want to know, what is the record for the highest number associations/collaborations between an actor/actress and a director. 
Not encompassing porn films for movies or extras for actors.

Comment: [List of film director and actor collaborations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_director_and_actor_collaborations)

Comment: Thanks for the list. It seems like the record is by John Ford / John Wayne who worked on 21 movies together.

Comment: On the other hand I'd wager there might be a much bigger chance to find high collaboration rather among the less famous/significant actors. There might be some kind of entirely unknown background/side actor who's made an appearance in every single movie of some director. Or maybe some weird B movie director who produced like 50 movies, all with his pal in a supporting role. But I guess you're looking for more famous examples here.

Comment: Do we count directors who appeared in their own films?  If so, I'd say Alfred Hitchcock, who appeared as a cameo in nearly all of his films...

Comment: I'll assume that "in Hollywood" means feature-length movies with a big-ish budget, and not movies actually shot in the Los Angeles area.  Because my first thought was, it's got to be a porn actor/actress working with a director. Those are often shot in the San Fernando Valley, where the Walt Disney Studios and Sony are (and which is where I live). And there were a lot more of those movies than big-budget feature films. (Just sayin'.)

Answer (score 7):

The British Carry-On films franchise consists of 31 films, all directed by Gerald Thomas, the actors and their film appearances in the series who beat the John Wayne record are Kenneth Williams (25), Joan Sims (24) and Charles Haughtry (23) .

Comment: Hollywood.....?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Oh, I completely missed that, too, I admit.

Comment: Probably ought to remove this answer as it isn't an answer to the question asked.

Comment: *Hollywood* not having been explicitly stated in the title, this answer is useful to the *rest* of the world.

Comment: @Mazura [it was](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/42053/revisions) mentioned before the new edit.

Comment: It was in the body, but not in the title as stated by Mazura. I have removed it from the body so that the answer becomes valid because it seems good enough for what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

Malayalam director [J Sasikumar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Sasikumar) has done 84 movies with actor [Prem Nazir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prem_Nazir) in the lead role. Guess no one is ever gonna beat that.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Sasikumar)

> Sasikumar holds three world records: the records for most number of
>   films (141), most number of films having the same actor as hero (Prem
>   Nazir in 84 films) and the most number of films directed in a year (15
>   films in 1977)